# How I prepare a line Graph in Titanium for Android device?

Tags: titanium

A am Using Titanium SDK 3.0.0.GA and I want to show a line Graph on window. How I can perform this task. 
In iOS this is make easily with JS library. like:- Raphael, filamental Library. Titanium Appcelerator Graph Module.
i am using this but this is only working for iOS.

1. http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/
2. http://raphaeljs.com/

But, this is not provided for Android Device and Emulator.
Please Help me, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very use for me. this is work on both iOS and  Android easily.... thanks

http://dygraphs.com/

Comment: This method is used within a WebView and Not native.